# Anthology of Horror short stories - one is about kids who find a dead baby and worship it as a God

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I picked up a collection of short stories - possibly by one author, but more likely by several authors - about 15 years ago I would guess. One of the stories involved a young boy finding a dead baby and taking it into an underground sewer (?) He and several other kids become obsessed with it and bring it offerings and gifts as if it is some kind of God.

The only other story that I can vaguely remember involves a door-to-door salesman and zombies....

Answer (score 1):

The dead baby/sewer thing reminds me of a Harlan Ellison story where sort of like baby alligators occupying the sewers of Manhattan, it is unwanted children. It was called [Croatoan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croatoan_(Ellison)), like the lost colony.